# LAN devices can't reach IPv6 internet/WAN addresses

Tags: networking, arch-linux, routing, ipv6, systemd-networkd

I have set up a double-stack, two-interface computer as a router for home use,
but LAN devices can't reach the outside world with IPv6. (IPv4 works perfectly).
`traceroute` also stops at the router when run from a LAN device.
But the router itself *can* ping IPv6 internet addresses no problem, however.

I have the following topology: 
`ISP edge gateway <->(ext0) My router (int0)<-> Network switch <-> LAN devices`

I am very new to IPv6 and don't really have a deep understanding what I'm doing here :)
I know what makes up a ipv6 address and what prefixes are, but that's kinda it.

All LAN devices get proper global IPv6 addresses with DHCPv6-PD and Router Advertisements.
For simplicity's sake, I have nerfed all firewalls on the router for now, so it would not interfere (but I already set them up to work once I get this fixed).

Relevant systemd-networkd configs: (I have dnsmasq managing only IPv4, but I don't think it's relevant here)

cat /etc/systemd/network/20-external.network

```
[Match]
Name=ext0

[Network]
DHCP=yes
IPForward=yes
IPv6AcceptRA=yes
```

cat /etc/systemd/network/20-internal.network

```
[Match]
Name=int0

[Network]
Address=192.168.1.1/24
IPMasquerade=yes
IPv6SendRA=yes
DHCPv6PrefixDelegation=yes
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6

[IPv6SendRA]
RouterLifetimeSec=3600
```

With this setup I get the following on the router:

ip -6 a

```
2: int0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2001:xxxx:xxxx:5dc0:21e:6ff:fe45:4afa/64 scope global dynamic 
       valid_lft 1027438sec preferred_lft 1027438sec
    inet6 fe80::21e:6ff:fe45:4afa/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: ext0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 state UP qlen 1000
    inet6 2001:xxxx:xxxx:5d00::1000/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 1025156sec preferred_lft 1025156sec
    inet6 2001:xxxx:xxxx:5d00:21e:6ff:fe45:4afb/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 1062665sec preferred_lft 604772sec
    inet6 fe80::21e:6ff:fe45:4afb/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip -6 r

```
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2001:xxxx:xxxx:5d00::/64 dev ext0 proto ra metric 1024 expires 1062685sec pref medium
2001:xxxx:xxxx:5dc0::/64 dev int0 proto kernel metric 256 expires 1027308sec pref medium
2001:xxxx:xxxx:5dc0::/64 dev int0 metric 1024 pref medium
unreachable 2001:xxxx:xxxx:5dc0::/60 dev lo metric 1024 pref medium
2001:xxxx:xxxx:5d00::/56 via fe80::4265:a3ff:feec:1e74 dev ext0 proto ra metric 1024 expires 1062685sec pref medium
fe80::/64 dev ext0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev int0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::4265:a3ff:feec:1e74 dev ext0 proto ra metric 1024 expires 1792sec mtu 1500 pref medium
```

`ping` from my PC:

```
PING ipv6.google.com(prg03s05-in-x0e.1e100.net (2a00:1450:4014:80c::200e)) 56 data bytes
^C
--- ipv6.google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 1045ms
```

`traceroute` from my PC:

```
traceroute -6 ipv6.google.com
traceroute to ipv6.google.com (2a00:1450:4014:80d::200e), 30 hops max, 80 byte packets
 1  2001XXXXXXXX5DC0021E06FFFE454AFA.catv.pool.telekom.hu (2001:xxxx:xxxx:5dc0:21e:6ff:fe45:4afa)  0.265 ms  0.240 ms  18.795 ms
 2  * * *
 3  * * *
 4  * * *
[...]
```

Comment: You could run ping from the PC and test with `tcpdump` on the router's `int0` and `ext0` interfaces if the ICMPv6 packages are entering and leaving the router (e.g. `tcpdump -ni int0 icmp6`).

Comment: when I start the traceroute I get from `tcpdump -ni int0 icmp6`:
`IP6 2001:xxxx:xxxx:5df2:21e:6ff:fe45:4afa > 2001:xxxx:xxxx:5df2:93cf:fee4:532e:5f76: ICMP6, time exceeded in-transit for 2a00:1450:400d:808::200e, length 88`

and from `tcpdump -ni ext0 icmp6`:
`IP6 2001:4c4c:12c6:5d00:21e:6ff:fe45:4afb > 2001:xxxx:xxxx:5d00:4265:a3ff:feec:1e74: ICMP6, destination unreachable, unreachable port, 2001:xxxx:xxxx:5d00:21e:6ff:fe45:4afb udp port 28494, length 258` @Dubu

Comment: also, if I ping, I get from `tcpdump -ni int0 icmp6`:

`IP6 2001:xxxx:xxxx:5d00:4265:a3ff:feec:1e74 > 2001:xxxx:xxxx:5df2:93cf:fee4:532e:5f76: ICMP6, destination unreachable, unknown unreach code (5)`